# Improper Integral in an old manuscript

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was reading through an old manuscript and came across the following "elementary exercise:"

$\int^\infty_0 \dfrac{1}{1+x^2 \sin^2 x} dx$.

Anyone have a clever way of seeing this? I haven't done decent integration in so long, I have a feeling I'm just overlooking something simple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Don't know how I wrote indefinite or why real numbers appeared, old age I suppose.

Comment: Is the exercise to compute the value or to show that it converges?  What is the manuscript about?

Comment: To compute the value. It's a manuscript on Real Analysis, with emphasis being placed on Riemann vs. Lebesgue integration in this section.

Comment: are you familiar with residue calculus?

Comment: Only briefly, I just started reading Complex Analysis by Ahlfors to refresh me on this. I had a feeling this was where it may be going.

Answer (score 1):

The value is $\infty$.  Note that for 
positive integers $n$,
$$ \int_{(n-1/2) \pi}^{n \pi} \dfrac{dx}{1 + x^2 \sin^2 x} \ge \int_{(n-1/2) \pi}^{n\pi}\dfrac{1}{1 + (n \pi)^2 \sin^2 x} = \dfrac{\pi}{2\sqrt{n^2 \pi^2 + 1}}  $$

Comment: Not sure I follow. I have, painstakingly, confirmed the last equality. But this would indicate to me that the values for large n are relatively small, and hence it possibly converges.

Comment: For large *n*, the radical is $\simeq n$, and our sum becomes $\simeq\frac\pi2\sum_1^\infty\frac1n=\infty$, since the [harmonic sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) diverges.

Comment: Ahh, thank you for clarifying.